# flex-wrap not really working in IE?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, flexbox

so I have this problem with my page in IE11.
I have 9 boxes with slightly different heights, that should be in a nice order like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNNGf.png

Im using display:flex and flex-wrap:wrap for that. It works in all other browsers, except IE. There it looks like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdWGv.png

I found out that flexbox doesn't really work with IE so I tried a few fixes, but none of them worked. (setting a different width // display: -ms-flexbox; // flex: 1 1 auto; ....)
Does someone know a solution for that and can help me?

My HTML code looks something like that:

```
<div class="row flexy">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            //Inhalt
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            //Inhalt
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            //Inhalt
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            //Inhalt
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            //Inhalt
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            //Inhalt
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            //Inhalt
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            //Inhalt
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            //Inhalt
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS is just that:

```
.flexy {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

When I resized the window I noticed that it only wraps weird if the last box in the first row has a smaller height. If the first box would be the smallest, then it would look like it should.

Comment: Since `flex-wrap` work in IE, it would be great if you could provide a working code snippet reproducing the issue, with the correct Bootstrap version and all. Also, it appears you use Bootstrap 3.xx, which is  based on `float` and will likely create more issues. I suggest you use Bootstrap 4, which is based on Flexbox

Comment: I agree, if at all possible, you should switch to 4.  It will fix itself.  If this is a large, legacy app where that would be more trouble than its worth, you could make a similar stand alone demo using 4, and compare the css used with a tool like this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-used/cdopjfddjlonogibjahpnmjpoangjfff.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that there is Bootstrap 4 already. Im going to try that first. Thank you.